# How to make an image fit into a circular frame in android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have a `ListView` in which there is an `ImageView`, the image in the `ImageView` gets loaded dynamically after its fetched from the server.
Now, I want these images, of any size, to fit into a circular frame, how to do that?
Here's a sample pic of what I want

[image]

Comment: Try this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882180/how-to-set-bitmap-in-circular-imageview

hope it will help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set bitmap in circular imageview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882180/how-to-set-bitmap-in-circular-imageview)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With the help of previous answer I came up with this solution.Hope it help others:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
 import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class CircleImage extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.circle_layout);
    ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.hair_four);
    Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 100, 100, true);
    Bitmap conv_bm = getRoundedRectBitmap(resized, 100);
    img1.setImageBitmap(conv_bm);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public static Bitmap getRoundedRectBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
    Bitmap result = null;
    try {
        result = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);

        int color = 0xff424242;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 200, 200);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 50, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError o) {
    }
    return result;
}

 }
```

Comment: For a slightly more efficient implemention, refer to Romain Guy's recent [**Android Recipe #1, image with rounded corners**](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/) blog post. The main difference is it uses a `BitmapShader` to directly control the visible 'textured' area, which simplifies the drawing logic to a single draw call.

Comment: Hey Sanghita ,I came across the same requirement and happened to use your code though it works fine as for displaying the image i have a issue.I replaced the following line of code with mine to increase the image view as canvas.drawCircle(90, 90,90, paint); since canvas.drawCircle(50, 50,50, paint); gave a small display view.However only 1 quarter of the image was being displayed in the imageview.Can u please help?

Comment: change the following lines as:                                        Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 600, 600, true);
Bitmap conv_bm = getRoundedRectBitmap(resized, 600);                   result = Bitmap.createBitmap(950, 950, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 650, 650);                canvas.drawCircle(300, 300, 300, paint);

Comment: @Sanghita,is it necesssary to specify the dimensions here.Bcoz i am targetting multiple device sizes i dont want to set the dimensions as u mentioned since it takes up fixed size.Can the image be set as per the size of the imageview defined in the xml file?Also i changed to this canvas.drawCircle(130, 130,130, paint); But i dont understand how to manipulate other parameters ;doing so does not render entire image.

Comment: @joy-since the circle is created through coding match_parent/wrap_content will not be available,changing only your canvas size doesnot effect the image's size

Comment: @Sanghita,you are right.However when i try to set the image into this circle only part of the image is displayed into that circle after i modified the other values.So i asked how to identify what parameter values do i need to set.like in for  Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 600, 600, true); Bitmap conv_bm = getRoundedRectBitmap(resized, 600); result = Bitmap.createBitmap(950, 950, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 650, 650);if the canvas drawn is canvas.drawCircle(130, 130,130, paint);

Comment: i want to get the circle bigger in size with image also bigger how can i do that.

Comment: Good luck recovering from that OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: @sanghita - can you guys please explain how to change the size of the circle been drawn with this code ! the image cropping and everything else is perfect but cant understand how to increase or decrease the radius of the circle

Comment: the image is positioned from the top left. how do I center the image? I want it to be scaleType:centerCrop.

Comment: nice example @Sanghita great job

Answer (score 9):

Try this code:

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedRectBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
try {
result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas = new Canvas(result);

color = 0xff424242;
paint = new Paint();
rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
rectF = new RectF(rect);
roundPx = pixels;

paint.setAntiAlias(true);
canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
paint.setColor(color);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
// return bitmap;
} catch (OutOfMemoryError o){}
return result;
}
```

If you want an actual circle then you can pass `100px` as parameter.

Comment: thanks a ton for your help , the solution you provided was for pictures in a rounder corners rectangle without size modification.it needed just a few lines of changes

Comment: @ricintech- can you guys please explain how to change the size of the circle been drawn with this code ! the image cropping and everything else is perfect but cant understand how to increase or decrease the radius of the circle

Answer (score 8):

**Update**

There is a [`CircleImageView`](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) available on Github.

You can get latest version from [Maven repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22de.hdodenhof%22%20AND%20a%3A%22circleimageview%22) as add as a gradle dependency.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of tutorial regarding this. I think it will help.

https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView

https://github.com/wisemandesigns/CircularImageView

https://coderwall.com/p/hmzf4w

Answer (score 1):

**We can manage the height and width of an image from xml code and draw circle/oval from java code like**

```
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
            />
```

> **for oval view**

```
ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        R.drawable.user_image);
Bitmap conv_bm = getRoundedBitmap(bm);
img1.setImageBitmap(conv_bm);


public static Bitmap getRoundedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    final Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = Color.RED;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    bitmap.recycle();

    return output;
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following dependancies

```
 implementation 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.2.1'
 implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
```

CircularImageView available for image fit in circle also if image is not looking proper .resize is for image resizing in circular image view.

```
    CircleImageView img;
    String Imageid; 

    Imageid="ImageName"; //String is not compulsary it may be drawable  

    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(Imageid.get(position)) //Load the image
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background) //Image resource for error
            .resize(20, 20)  // Post processing - Resizing the image
            .into(img); // View where image is loaded.
```

Answer (score 0):

**circleCrop()** will help if you are loading the image using Glide.

```
  Glide.with(context)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .circleCrop()
    .into(imageView)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static Bitmap getCircleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        final Bitmap circuleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getWidth(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(circuleBitmap);

        final int color = Color.RED;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getWidth());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        bitmap.recycle();

        return circuleBitmap;
    }
```