# Circular ImageView

Tags: android, android-view

I have been looking at how to create a round ImageView in Android. After reading questions already asked on the subject on StackOverflow at:

[How to make an image fit into a circular frame in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050813/how-to-make-an-image-fit-into-a-circular-frame-in-android)

and

[How to set bitmap in circular imageview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882180/how-to-set-bitmap-in-circular-imageview)

I have put together my own ImageView using the links as a guide that does what I need it to do: a rounded image with a border.

Below is the code that I am using:

```
public class CircularImageView extends ImageView
{

private int borderWidth = 5;
private int viewWidth;
private int viewHeight;
private Bitmap image;
private Paint paint;
private Paint paintBorder;
private BitmapShader shader;

public CircularImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setup();
}

public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setup();
}

public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setup();
}

private void setup()
{
    // init paint
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    paintBorder = new Paint();
    setBorderColor(Color.BLUE);
    paintBorder.setAntiAlias(true);     
}

public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth)
{
    this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    this.invalidate();
}

public void setBorderColor(int borderColor)
{       
    if(paintBorder != null)
        paintBorder.setColor(borderColor);

    this.invalidate();
}

private void loadBitmap()
{
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) this.getDrawable();

    if(bitmapDrawable != null)
        image = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
}

@SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    //load the bitmap
    loadBitmap();

    // init shader
    if(image !=null)
    {
        // Create a shader with a scaled bitmap to match the view dimensions            
        shader = new BitmapShader(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), false), Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        int circleCenter = viewWidth / 2;

                    // Draw the outer border
                    canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth, paintBorder);
        // circleCenter is the x or y of the view's center
        // radius is the radius in pixels of the cirle to be drawn
        // paint contains the shader that will texture the shape            
        canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter, paint);
    }       
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    int width = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);        

    viewWidth = width - (borderWidth *2);
    viewHeight = height - (borderWidth*2);

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

private int measureWidth(int measureSpec)
{
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            // We were told how big to be
            result = specSize;
        } else {
            // Measure the text
            result = viewWidth;

        }

    return result;
}

private int measureHeight(int measureSpecHeight, int measureSpecWidth) {
    int result = 0;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpecHeight);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpecHeight);

    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        // We were told how big to be
        result = specSize;
    } else {
        // Measure the text (beware: ascent is a negative number)
        result = viewHeight;           
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

I am planning on making this open source and would therefore appreciate it if someone could have a look over the code to ensure I am doing everything correctly.

Comment: First of all, thanks for sharing your code! I'm not quite sure the stackoverflow format is suitable for / meant for code reviews, unless you have *specific* questions and or issues with the code at hand. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ seems a more appropriate place, or an Open Source host like GitHub that effective allows code reviews through pull requests.

Comment: As @Paul-Jan said use codereview.stackexchange.com, and secondly, its better do create a custom drawable for this kind of thing. See http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/ which is the most memory efficient way of doing what your doing.

Answer (score 2):

Try this function to get round-corner image:

```
   private Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) 
    {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = pixels;
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not so strict about the border of the buttons. then why dont you make a round PNG image file with transparent edges.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way and you may not be able to change a lot of properties, but it is surely the easiest way. I just used [this](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview) library and I made a circular imageview that has also a border.

---

So, this is my solution:

**First**, I put this in my `build.grandle`:

```
`compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'`
```

**Second**, I put this in my `.xml` layout file:

```
 <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.CircularImageView
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:id="@+id/photo"
                    app:siBorderWidth="5dp"
                    app:siBorderColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

In my `.java` file, this is the way I can take or set the image to the `CircularImageView`:

```
final com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.CircularImageView photo = (com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.CircularImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);

photo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.female);
```

---

That's all I've done to do the an image circular with white border.

Answer (score 0):

Add Latest dependency compatible  with android x

```
implementation 'com.github.arefhosseini:android-shape-imageview:1.0.3'
```